# Lucene .NET Azure Blob storage and IFilter

Tags: azure, lucene.net, ifilter

What would be the best way to use IFilter to extract textual content from pdf/word/whatever in an Azure solution?

I've seen examples of IFilter that use a stream, but what should the content of the stream be?
Should it contain some sort of OLE headers and what not?

Sending the raw file content as a stream to IFilter doesnt seem to work.

Or would it be better to save the files to local file storage and let the IFilter read them from that location?

Answer (score 1):

using ifilter in azure will be tricky because several of the ifilters that are common on a desktop aren't available in an azure web/worker role.

You could create a durable VM in azure and install the missing ifilters.

However, if you're going to build your lucene index via a webupload you could just process the files into text as they are uploaded, and then index the text, and save the file off separately.  Add a field to your index that lets you get back to the original source document.

Might be an easier way, but that's how I solved the same issue.